# $http sync call to other $http in other file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, synchronization, angular-services

I want to read URL from one json file and feed URL to other javascript file having $http GET request to execute that URL. I am using one service
in another service file for getting data. Whenver I run it, it says undefined in **bannerslides** function.

**File: common.js**

```
(function() {
    angular.module('siteModule')
    .service('loggerService', function ($http, $q) 
    {   var rox;
        var deffered = $q.defer();
         $http.get('/config/config.json').then(function (data)
         {
                deffered.resolve(data);
         });

         this.getPlayers = function ()
            {
                return deffered.promise;
            }
    })
})();
```

**File: siteService.js**

```
(function() {
     var confUrl;
    angular.module('siteModule')
    .service('siteService', function ($http, $q, loggerService) 
    {

         loggerService.getPlayers().then(function (data) {
            confUrl = data.data.baseUrl+data.data.urls.site;
            console.log("GOTURL",confUrl);

         });

        this.bannerSlides = function(){
              console.log("URL NOT GET",confUrl);
             return $http({
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: confUrl
             }).then(function (response) {
                 // inspect/modify the received data and pass it onward
                 return response.data;
             }, function (error) {
 // inspect/modify the data and throw a new error or return data
                 throw error;
             });
        }
  })

})();
```

Comment: There is no need of html here ,just run js code in script tag of dummy html , just try to solve how we can get confUrl in bannerslides function from 
getplayers function.

Answer (score 1):

This is because all `$http` calls are async. You will need to chain your promises up. Fetch your url from json first, then call it. aka move your `loggerService.getPlayers()` into your `this.bannerSlides` function.

Before that, why do you need `$q` in your logger service? `$http` itself is already a promise.

common.js:

```
(function() {
  angular.module('siteModule')
    .service('loggerService', function($http) {
      this.getPlayers = function() {
        return $http.get('/config/config.json')
      }
    })
})();
```

siteService.js:

```
(function() {
  var confUrl;
  angular.module('siteModule')
    .service('siteService', function($http, $q, loggerService) {
      this.bannerSlides = function() {
        loggerService.getPlayers().then(function(data) {
          confUrl = data.data.baseUrl + data.data.urls.site;
          console.log("GOTURL", confUrl);
          //move your return statement here 
          return $http({
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: confUrl
          })
        });
      }
    })
})();
```

Comment: angular.js:14324 Error: [$http:badreq] Http request configuration url must be a string or a $sce trusted object.  Received: undefined

It is showing error . It is still getting undefined there

Comment: edited my answer. check one by one - is your logger service returning the url you want?

Comment: then check if your `confUrl` is correct. If it is not, something is wrong with the logger service itself - on the config.json

Comment: **confUrl is undefined  when I use it **
 `return $http({
          method: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          url: confUrl
        })`
**but when i use below code it works fine**
 
`return $http({
          method: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          url: "http://urlpath.com/data"
        })`

Comment: **Now it is giving other error**
`angular.js:14324 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (siteController.js:21)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4839)
    at $controllerInit (angular.js:10692)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:9569)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8878)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8881)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8881)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8881)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8881)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:8743)`